# What prepositions are to be used with verb 'fawn'?

Tags: prepositions

How do we use verb fawn (flattery) in a sentence?

In most of uses, I see use of 'over'. e.g. Philip fawned over Solomon for promotion. Sometime I see 'upon'. Philip fawns upon Solomon.
I also see use of 'on'.

Can I just omit preposition altogether. e.g. Philip fawned Solomon for promotion

Comment: No, because _fawn_ is an intransitive verb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fawn-over-on-sb